# Page not responding to Div tags

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've created a page that has a picture gallery. On the page, there are images and underneath the image are the descriptions. When you view it on Desktop it looks fine. However, when you view on a tablet or mobile device the images are fine but the descriptions is not staying in a nice little box, it ends up running the height of the page. How can I fix this?

I tried wrapping the page in a div so I can put the width to auto, and nothing. The page is not responding to my div. I used Bootstrap studio to build the page. Please help.

Below is my some of the pages code and the CSS. I did the CSS to see if it was working and its not.

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div class="col"></div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
            <div class="card"><h5  align="center">Box Braids</h5>
                <img class="card-img w-100 d-block" src="assets/img/Medium%20boxbraids600.jpg">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-text">Box braids are one of the most requested and versatile styles. Their sizes range from small to extra large, and their length can range from above the shoulders to down the back. This low maintenance style can be styled in such
                        a way that you can go from the gym to the boardroom and be aesthetically prepared to attend both functions. Let our professional stylist help to bring your box braids style ideas to life.&nbsp;<br></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: The page will need to be responsive rather then fixed. [https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp)

Comment: As you can see im new to this however. I designed this mobile first, so im not sure why its doing this.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: There's no CSS... You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) (icon looks like a page with `<>`) to include the HTML and CSS needed to recreate the situation you are experiencing.

Comment: Did you add the proper libraries and required stylesheets? You can check responsiveness using the chrome console as well.

Comment: Recommendation to asking better questions :) --  In addition to the HTML, please provide the CSS and, if possible, a link to a demo (you could use https://codepen.io/ or https://jsfiddle.net/).